Whether there is foliation version of Fubini's theorem for infinite dimensional space?
Whether there are probability measures in infinite-dimensional Spaces such that foliations are finite-dimensional, the Fubini's theorem holds?

Yes.  The version of Fubini's theorem in Rudin, "Real and Complex Analysis", Theorem 7.8, requires only that $(X, \mathscr S, \mu)$ and
$(Y, \mathscr T, \lambda)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.  Gaussian measures on infinite-dimensional spaces are  finite measures, so they are included.

Thank you very much for your answer. Maybe the setting of my question is not clear, we would like to have the version of the Foliation, not the usual version of the product measure.

You can edit your question. Why don't you make it clearer by specifying exactly what version of Fubini you do want?

Thanks for telling me. I am very sorry that I have sent a new question
